# Catch the moment when theme is deleted

Tags: theme-development

WordPress 5.8.1

functions.php

```
add_action( 'deleted_theme', 'nonverbis_delete_extra_table', 10, 2 );
function nonverbis_delete_extra_table( $stylesheet, $deleted ){
    error_log("delete_extra_table", 0);
}
```

What I do:

[image]

[image]

The log is empty. I mean that everything that this function does is writing "delete_extra_table" to the log. I don't have a debugger, so, I use writing to log for the debug purpose.

But the log is empty. This means that either a hook is wrong. Or some params (10, 2). Or I confused something else (like log or something).

To the best of my understanding, this line should have appeared in the log after I had pressed "Delete".

Could you help me understand why nothing has been written to the log?

And of course, the table has not been dropped.

Comment: If that code is in the theme then it's not going to run because the code was deleted when the theme was deleted.

Comment: You are right. But what hook should I use? I want to drop the database table I created for this theme.

Comment: You could only do it when switching theme with [`switch_theme`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/switch_theme/). Themes don’t normally create database tables. That sort of thing usually belongs in plugins, which have the appropriate capabilities for cleaning up when deleted.

Answer (score 0):

There are two direct actions that you can hook into while deleting a theme

```php
do_action( 'delete_theme', $stylesheet );
```

And

```php
do_action( 'deleted_theme', $stylesheet, $deleted );
```

Now about the `error_log()` function, you seem to be missing a argument, the destination.
One of my debugging tool is a custom error_log function, this is its code.

```php
error_log(print_r($some_value, true), 3, __DIR__ . '/log.txt');
error_log("\r\n\r\n", 3,  __DIR__ . '/log.txt');
```

This will create a `log.txt` file in the same folder where you called this functions.  If you use this in `functions.php` the `log.txt` will be in the root of your theme.